# Exterior differential equation in 3D

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, differential-topology, exterior-algebra, de-rham-cohomology

Let $f$ and $\beta$ be a scalar field and a $1$-form, respectively, on a 3-manifold $M$. The following is an equation for a $1$-form $\xi$:

$$\mathrm d \xi + \mathrm d f\wedge  \xi = \mathrm d \beta \,,$$
or, setting $g=e^f$,
$$\mathrm d (g \xi ) = g \mathrm d \beta  \,.$$

Does it admit a solution for $\xi$?

It is probably very easy to see, especially if I knew EDS, but I don't...
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No EDS needed here. This is just basics. Assuming the $3$-manifold is simply connected (or else we can only answer locally), necessary and sufficient for $g\,d\beta$ to be exact is that it be closed. And it is closed iff $dg\wedge d\beta=0$, which holds iff $df\wedge d\beta = 0$. Without knowing anything more about your original $f$ and $\beta$, I can't say anything more.

Comment: Got it. In the case where $\mathrm d g \wedge \beta = 0$ one clearly obtains a solution $\xi=\beta$. But I guess in general one can still have solutions for $\mathrm d g \wedge \beta \neq 0$, right?

Comment: Sure. The Poincaré Lemma gives you a local solution on a ball, say. If $d(g\,d\beta) = 0$, then it will give you an explicit formula for a $1$-form $\eta$ with $d\eta = g\,d\beta$, and then you take $\xi = \frac1g\eta$. We can't usually write down a formula on a manifold, but if $H^2(M) = 0$, then we know abstractly that every closed $2$-form is exact. When $M$ is compact (oriented), it follows from Poincaré duality, that if $M$ is simply connected (or, more generally, if $H_1(M)=0$), this cohomology will vanish.